# C# - Encode ASF with a custom data stream

Tags: c#, directshow, asf, wmf

I'm trying to create an ASF file and instead of using sound or video data I want to create a stream made of custom packets with binary data.

Can someone provide a code example of a couple of things : 
1) setting up a profile.
2) configuring a custom stream
3) inserting custom packets into the stream.

Much appreciated.
Thanks!

Thanks
Roey

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since I did this, but I'll give it a shot.

Using the Windows Media Format SDK, you would create a IWMWriter and configure how many streams it has.  You would set the [input properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757484(VS.85).aspx) for each stream to NULL, which tells it not to compress each sample.  After that, you just do a IWMWriter::WriteSample(...).

I'm sorry I don't remember all the rest of the details.

Answer (score 0):

For pre-compressed data you need to use IWMWriterAdvanced::WriteStreamSample
Note your bit rate setting may cause data loss.